# React stale closure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I have a hook that has a queue for frames. Each sent frame should be pushed onto the queue, but it seems like this isn't the case:

```js
frameQueue = { id : { someFrame }};

addFrameToQueue = id => {
   frameQueue[id] = data; // data is provided through closure
}

removeFrameFromQueue = id => {
   delete frameQueue[id]; // frameQueue[id] is undefined
}
```

The Id's are correct. Debugger shows that `frameQueue` is empty. Should I be using a `useRef` or a `useCallback` with the frameQueue as a dependent, or should I just provide it as a function parameter ?

Comment: You should not mutate the data directly on React. Instead use state to update the data.

Comment: Is frameQueue a state or a ref? Which closure are your taking about because in the above code there isn't a restricted closure which doesn't change